# XPath/XSLT generation

Tags: xslt, xpath

How can i get the cust_account_id value and the party_id value from this xml? (see ** portions) Thank you .

Essentially i want the xpath/xslt to drill down and find where cust_account_id is the name and for where it is the name pull out the value

```
<soap-env:Body xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">[[
      <WF_EVENT_T xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/xdb/APPS_NE/EBSCustomerService">
        <PRIORITY xmlns="">50</PRIORITY>
        <SEND_DATE xmlns="">2017-05-02T12:14:28.000-04:00</SEND_DATE>
        <RECEIVE_DATE xsi:nil="true" xmlns="" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
        <CORRELATION_ID xsi:nil="true" xmlns="" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
        <PARAMETER_LIST xmlns="">
          <PARAMETER_LIST_ITEM>
            <NAME>USER_ID</NAME>
            <VALUE>1569</VALUE>
          </PARAMETER_LIST_ITEM>
          <PARAMETER_LIST_ITEM>
            <NAME>RESP_ID</NAME>
            <VALUE>20678</VALUE>
          </PARAMETER_LIST_ITEM>
          <PARAMETER_LIST_ITEM>
            <NAME>RESP_APPL_ID</NAME>
            <VALUE>222</VALUE>
          </PARAMETER_LIST_ITEM>
          <PARAMETER_LIST_ITEM>
            <NAME>SECURITY_GROUP_ID</NAME>
            <VALUE>0</VALUE>
          </PARAMETER_LIST_ITEM>
          **<PARAMETER_LIST_ITEM>
            <NAME>CUST_ACCOUNT_ID</NAME>
            <VALUE>6049</VALUE>
          </PARAMETER_LIST_ITEM>**
          **<PARAMETER_LIST_ITEM>
            <NAME>PARTY_ID</NAME>
            <VALUE>34842</VALUE>
          </PARAMETER_LIST_ITEM>**
          <PARAMETER_LIST_ITEM>
            <NAME>CUST_ACCOUNT_PROFILE_ID</NAME>
            <VALUE xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
          </PARAMETER_LIST_ITEM>
          <PARAMETER_LIST_ITEM>
            <NAME>P_CREATE_PROFILE_AMT</NAME>
            <VALUE>T</VALUE>
          </PARAMETER_LIST_ITEM>
        </PARAMETER_LIST>
        <EVENT_NAME xmlns="">oracle.apps.ar.hz.CustAccount.create</EVENT_NAME>
        <EVENT_KEY xmlns="">oracle.apps.ar.hz.CustAccount.create55259</EVENT_KEY>
        <EVENT_DATA xmlns=""/>
        <FROM_AGENT xmlns="">
          <NAME>WF_BPEL_QAGENT</NAME>
          <SYSTEM>EBSDEV.CLI.AD</SYSTEM>
        </FROM_AGENT>
        <TO_AGENT xsi:nil="true" xmlns="" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
        <ERROR_SUBSCRIPTION xsi:nil="true" xmlns="" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
        <ERROR_MESSAGE xsi:nil="true" xmlns="" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
        <ERROR_STACK xsi:nil="true" xmlns="" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
    </WF_EVENT_T>
    </soap-env:Body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple:

```
select="//PARAMETER_LIST_ITEM[NAME='CUST_ACCOUNT_ID']/VALUE
```